# Why can't I track some meta badges progress?

Tags: support, badges

On my profile page I cannot track progress to [community-event](/questions/tagged/community-event) and [screenshot-of-the-week](/questions/tagged/screenshot-of-the-week) tag badges, while I have some answers and positive score for them.

I can only track these:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned [here:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

> A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be eligible for tag badges.

[community-event](/questions/tagged/community-event) only has 35 questions, and [screenshot-of-the-week](/questions/tagged/screenshot-of-the-week) only has 5.

Comment: all right, let's have more of these community-events then!

Comment: @arghtype sounds like a good idea.